# Why does calling this method statically work?

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

```
class Duck {
  public function quack() {
    $this­->swim();
  }
  public function swim() {
    echo 'I\'m swimming!';
  }
}
class Plane {
  public function fly() {
    Duck::quack(); 
  }
  public function swim()
  {
  echo 'I can\'t swim! People are DROWNING!';
  } 
}
$plane = new Plane(); 
$plane-­>fly();
```

I got asked the above question and gave the answer that the output is an error illegally calling static method.
But it actually prints "I'm swimming!".
Could somebody please explain why this happens?

Comment: PHP5.3.10 ubuntu says I can't swim! People are DROWNING! __LOL__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to note with **PHP 5.3** (and public methods):

**CAN** call public methods statically from anywhere INSIDE Object context (only if inside instantiated object)...even if not declared static

```
Duck::quack();
```

**CANT** call protected method in same scenario.

```
Duck::quack(); //error
protected function quack() { }
```

**CANT** call public properties (instance variables) statically from anywhere INSIDE Object context, unless declared static...

```
class Duck {
 public $hello = 'hello there';   
}
class Plane {
 Duck::$hello; //error
}
```

**CANT** call public methods (or properties) statically from OUTSIDE object context..unless declared static

```
Duck::quack(); //error
```

Other languages use this type of engine flexibility, calling any public method statically as long as from inside Object context.
As mentioned (by @poitroae) it works like this by default, but if you turn on `E_STRICT` you'll get an error.

***ALSO:***
It is a known idiosyncrasy with PHP that you should'nt be allowed to call `$this` in this Context. The program should be under Class Context at this point (being called statically) but `$this` works which is akin to Object Context. 
If this were a statically declared Method than calling `$this` would cause an instant fatal error.

Hope that helps

Comment: that explains alot, really appreciate it thanks. what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

It works by default, but if you turn on `E_STRICT` you'll get

```
PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method Duck::quack() should not be called statically in...
```

PHP sees that you wanted `swim()` to be actually static and so it let's you simply call it.